# screen is black when rendering in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

I have a light, and everything, but it renders black.

When I render it from the bottom toolbar it renders fine, when I click *Render Image*, or render it from the view of the camera, its black.

I would attach the blend file, but I don't know how to. I already tried putting in more lights, and messing with the layers, but it just wont work!

Does anyone mind telling me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Only apply if you cannot see by pressing F12**

Make sure you don't keep any hidden object in front of camera.

Check your right hand column if there is hidden object or not.

You can hide by clicking on eye stuff click again for un-hide.